# Search/Delete field with period from ElasticSearch when a nested document with same structure exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I accidentally created a field with periods when I was using the Bulk API to update nested documents. Now, my documents have a nested document and a field name with the same structure. For example, the structure is similar to the following:

```
{
  "foo":{
    "bar": 123
  },
  "foo.bar": 123
}
```

This is causing problems when I do queries against my index. How can I go about finding documents with the top-level field "foo.bar" and delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a script in a [partial update call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document) like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/123/_update -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"foo.bar\")"
}'
```

**UPDATE:** If you need to remove that field for all documents that contain it, there's another solution using the [update-by-query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery). In one shot, you can specify which documents to update and what to update in the matching documents, like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/_update_by_query -d '{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "exists": {"field": "foo.bar"}
            }
        }
    },
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"foo.bar\")"
}'
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can search for those documents?

Comment: I was able to remove the fields with the script you had written earlier. I didn't use the update-by-query plugin because there seems to be a problem with ES 1.6, https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/issues/38. All in all, thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of problem are you seeing?

Comment: I didn't try it out. I just wanted to point out that there's an open issue on the plugin with respect to ES 1.6.